# Discord app not showing tray icon unity

Tags: unity

First of all,I know that unity isn't supported anymore. But I still like it over gnome. So I installed unity and now the tray icon for discord isn't there anymore. Does it exists any fix for that?

Sorry for my bad English...

Comment: Unity is still supported. It is available in the Ubuntu software repositories. It only is not anymore maintained by Canonical, but depends on the wider community now.

Comment: Try to "whitelist" the application: install dconf-editor, and edit the key desktop.unity.panel systray-whitelist. Add the name of the process of your particular program. It will show up in the output of `ps ax`.

Comment: Glad to know that I still can use unity. I will try that with dconf as soon as I can

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1

try this :

```
 
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-top-icons-plus
```

### Solution 2

Download a browser extension called **GNOME Shell integration**

search for **"Tray Icons"**

trun it on